# Consolidating Pandas Dataframe on 1 column while retaining data from multiple rows in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How can I consolidate a dataframe like below on the User while retaining values from other columns?

**unconsolidated:** [image]

**df_consolidated:** [image]

Any advice welcomed, even around better practice for consolidating in situations like this.
The date column can be consolidated or keep the latest date, that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: instead of the photo, please add text of your dataframe

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos groupby and been searching since for a similar problem/solution. Trying things in jupyter.